# How to set shell used by system() to invoke bash scripts in R?

Tags: r, bash, system

I need to call `bash` scripts from an R session, but it seems that the default shell is `sh`, I obtain this, indeed:

```
> system(sprintf("echo $0")))

sh
```

How can I set `bash` as default shell?

Thanks!

PS: this happens from both Rstudio and from an R console (called from a bash terminal...)

Edit: Not really duplicate, as I am interested in setting the default shell, rather than calling `bash` once.

Comment: Try to see what `Sys.getenv('SHELL')` outputs.

Comment: Your title asks “How to set defult shell” while your question asks “call bash scripts”. Those are two different things, which one do you want?

Comment: @RuiBarradas `Sys.getenv('SHELL')` gives `bin/bash` . I also set up `R_SHELL` as enviroment variable, but still `system()` only calls `sh`

Comment: @DourHighArch my question asks `How can I set bash as default shell?` (but not at the first line). Let me know if I should edit. Hope can be voted as a non-duplicate.

Comment: `system()` **always** calls `sh`. In every language. This isn't an R thing -- it's the same way in C, or Python, or anything else. You don't need to change the shell `system()` invokes to be able to start bash scripts with it (though the best ways to invoke subprocesses don't involve an intermediate shell at all).

Comment: That said, reviewing the other question, it looks to me like the reopen vote was in error. The other question's accepted answer *clearly does* speak to why the OP's request is impossible (the R `system()` call directly invoking the C `system()` call, which is hardcoded to only use `sh`).

Comment: ...so, "set the default shell" assumes that there *is* such a thing as a "default shell" used by `system()`. Proof that there doesn't exist such a thing, and thus that it can't be set, may not be the answer you wanted, but is an answer to the question nonetheless.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  thanks, this is very helpful.